# Retrieve the answer to a request from a web site

Tags: html

I'm just trying to check every second this website and retrieve the answer to my request. If this answer changes I want to be informed by email.
Thanks for your help!

I found the query I was looking for with google inspector but I don't know how to retrieve it or even how to request it again in a loop

Comment: Every second? My site would block you.

Comment: Hi, please edit your tags according to the tech (languages/frameworks/libraries) that you are asking in the question. Please remove the unnecessary tags and add the tags accordingly